# Joi validate 2 schemas conditionally - Invalid schema content

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, joi

I'm trying to add conidial schema according of the value of the isCat field in the request body, here is what I have so far:
ror [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid schema content` error.
What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you remove `entity` and `put`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Joi.object({
  params: Joi.object({
    id: Joi.number().required().integer().min(1),
  }),
  body: Joi.object({
    code: Joi.string().required(),
  }).when(Joi.ref("$isValid"), {
    is: Joi.equal(true),
    then: Joi.object({
      body: Joi.object({
        ...entity,
      }),
    }),
    otherwise: Joi.object({
      body: Joi.object({
        ...put,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

Verify the reference given by you is right `Joi.ref("$isValid")`.
If you provide right reference, this schema will work as you expect.